# ".0" appended when converting number to text in SQLITE

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Using below casting query to convert number as text in my application.

**Select CAST(Orderid as TEXT) from orders**

If i run this i am getting output like
1234.0
1098.0

Instead of this i need to get the result like
1234
1098

I have tried the below query. If i use the below query, it returns the result in number format instead of string format in datatable.

**Select CAST(orderid as string) from orders**

How to achieve this through query? It should satisfy the following cases too.

Actual Value
12345
12345.234
12345.023

Expected value
12345
12345.234
12345.023

Please suggest a way to get result as string type when converting number as text 
in Sqlite. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the actual value of `orderid `?

Comment: OrderId is the column name in my table. Consider it is int type. It have values like below
10248
10249
10250

Comment: You really should do this type of conversion when you go to display the values in your UI code, not in your DB queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether removing the fractional digits would change the value:

```sql
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN CAST(orderid AS INTEGER) = orderid
                 THEN CAST(orderid AS INTEGER)
                 ELSE orderid
            END AS TEXT)
FROM orders;
```

Comment: Yes, this will work for my case. Thank you all for your quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

```
SELECT CAST(orderid AS int) FROM orders
```

Comment: If i did like this following case will fail.

Actual Value 10245.093
Expected value 10245.093

If i CAST like above i am getting 10245 as result.